# Bijection between two infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to get right answer to question:
**Can you make bijection between set ℝ\{-3} and set ℝ?**

I know those two sets are not same size but I think I can still make bijection, but I need mathematical proof.

Can someone tell me what is right answer + proof? +Is there way how to for example ask Wolfram for those questions?

Comment: Try to think about a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$ first.

Comment: @nicomezi Its same. One set have 1 element less than other. As I know for example Bijection between all and odd integers is bijection, so this is same right? If yes, can I ask then when are two infinite sets not bijection?

Answer (score 1):

Take any sequence, say $\{1,2,\cdots\}$. Let $f(x) =x$ if $x$ is not in the set $\{-3,1,2,\cdots\}$. Now map $-3$ to $1$, $1$ to $2$ etc. You get a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R \setminus \{-3\}$.

Comment: I know how to make bijection but I dont know how to make proof that its correct. I dont have any counter proof of situation when I cannot make bijection between two infinite sets

Comment: For any set $X$, infinite or not, you can never find a bijection between $X$ and the set of all the subsets of $X$, denoted $\mathcal{P}X$

Comment: @JuliusL33t this not helped me :D

Comment: For infinite sets $X$, you often find bijections between $X$ and some strict subset $Y \subset X$. You can find bijections between $\{0,1,2,3,...\}$ and $\{1,2,3,...\}$ although one is a strict subset of the other. So it's not immediately obvious that there are infinite sets of different sizes. This is the content of the statement "no bijection $X \to \mathcal{P}X$". $\mathcal{P}X$ is strictly larger.

Answer (score 0):

R{3} is the set of all real numbers **except** 3.  You say "I know those two sets are not same size".  Unfortunately, what you "know" is not true.  Both sets have the same cardinality, that of the set of real numbers.  What I would do is use the fact that the set of *integers* is "countable".  First map every non-integer to itself.  Since the set of integers is countable, it can be written in a "list", $a_1$, $a_2$, etc. so that every integer is some where on that list.  And we can always choose that list so that "3" is the first number.  One example might be "3, 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5" continuing in the obvious way.  The map 0-> 3, 1-> 0, -1->1, 2->-1,... where the rule is that every number on the list, other than 3, is mapped to the number just preceding it in that list.

Comment: So even that real numbers are uncountable we apply same rules to them (when mapping) as for integers?